# Allow to run Telegram (or any other application) via firejail, prevent it from running directly

Tags: sandbox, privacy, firejail

Preferably without using `sudo`.

So far I've just saved it under `/opt/telegram/Telegram` without adding it to `$PATH` but that's not a solution since I can easily run it accidentally.

Comment: Not sure how firejail works, how about changing ownership of the file and removing execute permission for your user?

Comment: Already tried that - "No permission to execute file"

Comment: Telegram start-up just worked from firejail command-prompt (bash). If you're in such situation, demanding extra caution - open Bash terminal with several tabs open and start the GUI applications from there, with or without firejail. This is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution to this problem is to 1) add `/opt/telegram` to `$PATH` and 2) create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/firejail /usr/local/bin/Telegram
```

Now Telegram will run automatically in a Firejail sandbox *when no absolute or relative path is specified*.

In other words, the following commands will start Telegram in a sandbox:

```
Telegram
firejail Telegram
firejail /opt/telegram/Telegram
/usr/bin/firejail Telegram
/usr/bin/firejail /opt/telegram/Telegram
```

The following command will still run Telegram without sandbox:

```
/opt/telegram/Telegram
```

You can verify that Telegram runs in a sandbox with `firejail --list` and `firejail --tree`.

Source: [man 1 firejail](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/firejail.1.html#DESKTOP_INTEGRATION), section `DESKTOP INTEGRATION`